# How to get hold of the Default BodyParser?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

What I'm asking is how to get hold of the **Default** Scala Play `BodyParser` implementation in 2.6. However, if you know a cleaner way to solve this use-case I'm more than happy to hear it.

Some preamble ... I reused a Java Play framework [Play-Authenticate](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate) (PA) to build a [Scala Play application](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala) on top. Yes crucify me for it! I wanted all the social authentication functionality but have my application in Scala and use e.g. Slick. Yes yes I could try rewriting PA in Scala but no time now ... thinking about it though.

Now that this is out of the way, here is my use case. I have Scala controllers and need to pass Java Context to the PA framework to be able to use it. I also need to check whether the user can be cookie-authenticated, namely whether the user checked the "Remember Me" box when she logged the first time. This "solution" used to work before migrating to Play 2.6 but now doesn't work because of the `BodyParser`.

This is what the "burger" looks like. I want to eat it so ... I need to authenticate the user by checking the incoming cookie but while at it a Java Context is created (to interoperate with PA). But since I have the dreaded Java Context I can make it available throughout the Scala Application in the scope of one request:

```
def index =
  TryCookieAuthAction { implicit jContext =>  // <==== this is the burger
    deadbolt.WithAuthRequest()() { implicit request =>
     Future {
        Ok(indexView(userService))
     }
  }
}
```

Now let's look at the cow. Pre 2.6 it used to work because I wasn't forced to override `parser` but now in 2.6 I'm forced to:

```
case class TryCookieAuthAction[A](block: Http.Context => Action[A])(implicit auth: PlayAuthenticate, config: Configuration, env: Environment, mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Action[A] {
  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result] = {
    val contextComponents = JavaHelpers.createContextComponents(config, env)
    val jContext = JavaHelpers.createJavaContext(request, contextComponents)

    TryCookieAuthAction.jContextDv += (request.id -> jContext)

    if(!auth.isLoggedIn(jContext)) {
      // calling Java here so need a Java Context
      auth.tryAuthenticateWithCookie(jContext)
    }

    val scalaResult: Future[Result] = Await.ready(block(jContext)(request), 60 seconds)

    val session : Seq[(String, String)] = jContext.session().keySet().toArray.map(key => (key.toString, jContext.session().get(key)))
    val cookies : Seq[Cookie] = jContext.response().cookies().asScala.toSeq.map(cookie =>
      Cookie(cookie.name(), cookie.value(), maxAge = Option(cookie.maxAge()), path = cookie.path(), domain = Option(cookie.domain()),
        secure = cookie.secure(), httpOnly = cookie.httpOnly())
    )

    TryCookieAuthAction.jContextDv -= request.id

    scalaResult.map(_.withSession(session : _*).withCookies(cookies : _*))
  }

  override def executionContext = ec

  override val parser: BodyParser[A] = ???
}

object TryCookieAuthAction {
  private lazy val jContextDv = TrieMap[Long, play.mvc.Http.Context]()

  /**
    * Extracts the Java context given a request
    * @param request The request
    * @tparam A The request body type
    */
  implicit class RequestToContext[A](request: Request[A]) {
    def jContextOption : Option[Http.Context] = jContextDv.get(request.id)
    def jContext : Http.Context = jContextDv(request.id)
  }

  def apply[A](action: Action[A])(implicit auth: PlayAuthenticate, config: Configuration, env: Environment, mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext): TryCookieAuthAction[A] = TryCookieAuthAction(_ => action)
}
```

My questions is how to get the Default `BodyParser` or is there a more clever way to do this? For example, creating an `ActionBuilder` I tried but then I can't make `jContext` implicitly available for the enclosed `Action`.

Comment: I don't envy what you're going to have to do here... but you will likely need to extend `ActionBuilder[A]` instead, and then `@Inject (parser: BodyParsers.Default)`. If I were you, I'd start fresh and try to adapt this code into one of the examples provided [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition). It won't be fun, but you should get there eventually.

Comment: By the way, there is a "default" body parser hiding somewhere in the Play libs... but it's deprecated and you'd be very naughty for using it

Comment: Using `play.core.j.JavaHelpers` is a lot naughtier 

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution or potentially *the* solution?

First by changing the `object WithJContextSupportAction`'s `apply` method to include `play.api.mvc.PlayBodyParsers` as implicit parameter:

```
def apply[A](action: Action[A])(implicit config: Configuration, env: Environment, bodyParsers: PlayBodyParsers, ec: ExecutionContext): WithJContextSupportAction[A] = WithJContextSupportAction(_ => action)
```

Then propagate the new implicit change to the action class:

```
case class WithJContextSupportAction[A](block: JContext => Action[A])(implicit config: Configuration, env: Environment,
                                                                      bodyParsers: PlayBodyParsers, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Action[A] {
```

Finally overriding the `parser` like so:

```
override def parser= bodyParsers.default.asInstanceOf[BodyParser[A]]
```